# Cookieless Domain Help

Tags: .htaccess, dns, cookieless

I've been reading a bit about serving my images, javascript and css from a seperate domain.

I have set up a domain, not a sub domain but a new account on my server.

My site is for example: `http://www.site.com`

I have set up a new account for `http://s1.site.com`

To cut it short, I have about 40gb of images, so rather me moving it (would also require me to update a few of my scripts as I have scrapers to grab images) I was wondering if there was a way to point my new sub-domain to my other content?

Basically, I want to create a .htaccess file on s1.site.com and get it to pull the info from www.site.com, for example:

```
http://www.site.com/images/picture.jpg
```

becomes

```
http://s1.site.com/images/picture.jpg
```

But the image doesn't really exist on the `s1.site.com`, we are just 'mirroring' it using htaccess to save the hassle of copying everything over to the static domain.

Please let me know how this is possible, as it would save me a great deal of time and would work wonders.

I basically just want to make anything on

`http://s1.site.com/*` pull from `/home/originalsite/public_html/(images/js/css folders)`

Comment: This could work with some simple tricks (the most obvious making the vhost point directly to your orignal folder, htaccess redirecting to a PHP with a readfile() could world too)... by the biggest question is why you would do this?

Comment: To serve content from a cookieless domain (to speed up page load time obviously) and to save me copying my files over to the new domain.

Comment: Do you have control of the `http.conf` file for this apache install?